# How to go to the function definition in Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, function, keyboard-shortcuts

This may be a silly question, but I was not able to get the answer. In c# when coded in VS, we use F12 to go to the definition of any function from the place its called.

But how do we navigate to the function definition from its call, for the functions defined within script tag?... particularly to **functions written using jQuery?**...

eg:

```
    <button value="Save" id="btnSave" onclick="save()">
    <script>
    function save()
    {
     check();
     //stmts
    }

    function check()
    {
     //stmts
    }
    </script>
```

here, how do I navigate to the save() function and from save to check()?.. I have may functions defined within the script tag, it becomes really difficult to copy, paste and find always.

Can someone please let me know a solution for this?..

Thanks all..;)

Comment: Depends on your IDE :) Which one you are using?

Comment: I think he meant , like in VS it's f12, or cntrl+click in java IDE, which unfortunately in dev tools is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio, add a reference in a comment to the library at the top of the file (or better its [-vsdoc variant](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery-vsdoc/1.10.2)).
E.g.

```
 /// <reference path="~/Scripts/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2-vsdoc.js"/>
```

Then F12 would work too for jQuery.

This is called [JavaScript IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx)

Comment: I am using MVC4 and should I add a reference like this at the top of the view in chtml page? But it isnt working for me...;(

Comment: @user2771399 I assumed a separate js file. It's a JavaScript comment, so maybe at the top of your script tag.

Comment: Sorry, when I added it at the top of script tag, its telling, "Element Reference is not supported" and the stmt doesnt look like a commented line...

Comment: @user2771399 Don't forget the '///' in front of the reference-tag